# linear and a projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Let X be the space of continuous functions f in the interval $[-1,1]$. Define Pf to be the even part of $f$, that is

$(Pf)(x)= \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$

Prove that P defined above is a projection.

I'm not sure how to show this. I saw something similar but it was in reference to the Fourier series. Is that the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$P^2f=P\left(\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2\right)=\frac12\left(Pf(x)+Pf(-x)\right)=$$

$$\frac12\left(\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2+\frac{f(-x)+f(-(-x))}2\right)=\;\ldots$$

Comment: Oh wow yes that was really  helpful. Thank  you alot :).